# Can I configure VPN on firebase test cloud device

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to execute espresso UI test on firebase test cloud devices and my staging environment is a VPN network. So, Is it possible to configure VPN on firebase test cloud or can we configure cisco any connect VPN on firebase test cloud devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could try whitelisting the Test Labs IP addresses for VPN-less access:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/get-started#ip-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's currently no way to configure the network for devices in Firebase Test Lab.  They are only able to access publicly available network resources.

Always feel free to file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to see if there's anything that can be done to suit your needs.